# Matrix Multiplication (I dont get all my values returned)

Tags: c++, c

Hi please can anyone help me figure out what i am doing wrong. Writing a function to perform matrix multiplication. I don't get all my values displayed. i am really confused here. Thanks (VERY new to C++)

```
    int MultiplyTwoMatrices(int **MatrixA, int rowA, int ColumnA, int **MatrixB, int rowB,    int columnB);
int **Matrixmultiply;       //I have allocated and freed it's memory
int rowA=4;
int rowB=4;
int columnA=4;
int columnB=4;

int main()
{
for ( x = 0; x < rowA; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < columnB; y++)
    {
    Matrixmultiply[x][y] = MultiplyTwoMatrices(MatrixA,rowA,columnA,MatrixB,rowB,columnB);
        cout<<Matrixmultiply[x][y] <<"\t";

    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int MultiplyTwoMatrices(int **MatrixA, int rowA, int ColumnA, int **MatrixB, int rowB,    int columnB)
{

int **temp = NULL;
int sum = 0;
double **Multiple = NULL;
int i=0, j=0;

temp = (int**)malloc(columnB*(sizeof(int*)));
for (int p=0; p<columnB; p++)
    {
        temp[p] = (int*)malloc(rowB*(sizeof(int))); 

    }

Multiple = (double**)malloc(rowA*(sizeof(double*)));
for (int p=0; p<rowA; p++)
    {
        Multiple[p] = (double*)malloc(columnB*(sizeof(double))); 

    }

for (int p =0; p<columnB; p++)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q<rowB; q++)
        {
            temp[p][q] = MatrixB[q][p];
        }

    }
for (i =0; i<rowA; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<columnB; j++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r<rowB; r++)
            {
            sum = sum + (MatrixA[i][r]  * temp[j][r]);
            }

            Multiple[i][j] = sum;
            return Multiple[i][j];
            //cout<<Multiple[i][j]<<"\t";
            sum=0;
        }
            //cout<<"\n";

    }


for (int p =0; p<columnB; p++)
    free (temp[p]);
    free(temp);
for (int p =0; p<rowA; p++)
    free (Multiple[p]);
    free(Multiple);
}
```

Comment: First of all if you are using c++ try to avoid using malloc, and use new instead. Malloc is predominately C code, and using new will make your life a lot easier! (and use delete instead of free)

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or just not displaying? If you are new to this stuff I would advise reading or even skimming the book by Flowers http://www.amazon.co.uk/An-Introduction-Numerical-Methods-C/dp/0198506937/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1361651970&sr=8-1

Comment: No errors. Just giving me same answer.. meaning it just does 1st row and second column addition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all theres A LOT of cleaning up needed in your code. It is good practice to keep functions self contained, so only pass the two matrix arguments in the function and do all the iterating in the function itself. A simple argument for this is efficiency, otherwise your code has to make n*m function calls, not good. So:

```
int MultiplyTwoMatrices(int **MatrixA, int **MatrixB){}
```

Even better, you are using C++ not C, so make use of objects! Encapsulate the int ** inside a matrix class, this will make your life a lot easier, you will only then need to pass object references around not pointers!

I really strongly advise you read the book I recommended as you will get the most out of C++.

Anyway the problem is you are returning inside the for loop. When you return the functions stops, therefore it is not iterating through the final for loop.